# Member 'GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(string)' cannnot be accessed with an instance refrence

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to fix this bug and its driving me nuts only the other Fixes I have checked say that you may have out something static I checked multiple times and I am 99% sure I do not have the problem with it being static this is the script I have beenb having Problems with

```
  private void Update() {
    if (Vector3.Distance(player.FindGameObjectWithTag("Tag").transform.position, lastEndPosition) < PLAYER_DISTANCE_SPAWN_LEVEL_PART) {
        SpawnLevelPart();
    }
}
```

Here is The full Code:

```
using System.Collections;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LevelGenerator : MonoBehaviour {

```
private const float PLAYER_DISTANCE_SPAWN_LEVEL_PART = 200f;

[SerializeField] private Transform levelPart_Start;
[SerializeField] private List<Transform> levelPartList;
[SerializeField] private GameObject player;

private Vector3 lastEndPosition;

private void Awake() {
    lastEndPosition = levelPart_Start.Find("EndPosition").position;

    int startingSpawnLevelParts = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < startingSpawnLevelParts; i++) {
        SpawnLevelPart();
    }
}

private void Update() {
    if (Vector3.Distance(player.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform.position, lastEndPosition) < PLAYER_DISTANCE_SPAWN_LEVEL_PART) {
        SpawnLevelPart();
    }
}

private void SpawnLevelPart() {
    Transform chosenLevelPart = levelPartList[Random.Range(0, levelPartList.Count)];
    Transform lastLevelPartTransform = SpawnLevelPart(chosenLevelPart, lastEndPosition);
    lastEndPosition = lastLevelPartTransform.Find("EndPosition").position;
}

private Transform SpawnLevelPart(Transform levelPart, Vector3 spawnPosition) {
    Transform levelPartTransform = Instantiate(levelPart, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    return levelPartTransform;
}
```

}

Comment: As your title says. Its GameObject not player. Its a method of the class not the instance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have Added a bit more code to help

Answer (score 1):

Rather than the problem being that you have something that's static, the problem in this case is that you need to be using the static method `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag()` rather than trying to access it from `player` which is an instance of `GameObject`.

```
  private void Update() {
    if (Vector3.Distance(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Tag").transform.position, lastEndPosition) < PLAYER_DISTANCE_SPAWN_LEVEL_PART) {
        SpawnLevelPart();
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed it for the sake of the stackoverflow thing

Comment: I’m not sure I’m understanding you but if you change it to match what’s shown in the answer it should solve your problem.